# How does TermPositions works in lucene?

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I have Lucene .Net index (currently running version 2.9.2, but i am going to upgrade to the new 3.0.3 soon).

For search performance issue, I need to create in-memory mapping from DocId to Application Id - so I will not need to fetch the stored value from the index (search result might return thousands of documents...). Since I have a lot on indexing iterations, I need to update \ recreate this mapping many times - so I need to do it fast.

I saw [this great article](http://invertedindex.blogspot.co.il/2009/04/lucene-dociduid-mapping-and-payload.html) that tries to solve exactly this problem, and compares the time by retrieving result using Lucene's `FieldCache` mechanism or using `TermPositions` enumeration on unique indexed field. As the author said, indeed creating that mapping using `TermPositions` is much faster the using Lucene's `FieldCache`, but its really important to me to understand why. Could some one explain to me what both `TermPositions` and `FieldCache` do behind the scenene?

Answer (score 0):

TermPositions in Lucene is an advanced feature.  I have only used it once (when migrating from 2.9.x to 3.0.3 RC2 like you were).  TermPositions are stored very efficiently using Tuple's which make access as a data structure fast and also it is small, so retrieving a payload with term "positions" is fast as well.

I actually ended up going through samples in the book called "Lucene in Action"...it is for Java, but it is based on Lucene 3.0.3, which was perfect for Lucene.NET 3.0.3 :)

I mention this, because FieldCache is covered pretty deep in that book and if you want to get under the covers (understand it deeply)...I would look there first.

BTW...that article is based on Lucene 2.2, 2.3->2.9.x was a pretty big jump when they added "near real-time search" and made a lot of methods obsolete...3.0.3 changes that as well, so their numbers may not reflect what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is quite simple. Lucene stores field values as strings. When you call `GetInts` and the values are not within the cache, it needs to read the strings, then parse them to Integers.

When you use payloads, you will encode your ints to an array of bytes, that you convert back to an int. This way, you simply ask Lucene to read 4 raw bytes at a given position and you convert back to an int.

The string reading/parse operations is what makes a big difference here